# How can I split and re-tidy the 2 arguments of a macro into 2 seperate macros?

Tags: c, macros

I want to define a macro which, when used like this:

```
ADD_TO_OPS("abc", 3)
ADD_TO_OPS("cdef", 2)
ADD_TO_OPS("xx", 4)
```

, will produce something like this:

```
#define OPS_NAMES      "abc", "cdef", "xx"
#define OPS_VALUES     3, 2, 4
```

In other words, I want `ADD_TO_OPS(NAME, VALUE)` to do the following things (the following code won't work, just let you see what I want to do):

```
#ifdef OPS_NAMES
#   define OPS_NAMES2   OPS_NAMES, NAME
#   undef OPS_NAMES
#else
#   define OPS_NAMES2   NAME
#endif
#define OPS_NAMES   OPS_NAMES2
#undef OPS_NAMES2

#ifdef OPS_VALUES
#   define OPS_VALUES2  OPS_VALUES, VALUE
#   undef OPS_VALUES
#else
#   define OPS_VALUES2  VALUE
#endif
#define OPS_VALUES  OPS_VALUES2
#undef OPS_VALUES2
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do.  Are you saying you want macros that create other #defines?  Can you show how you'd like to use these in your code?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using something called an X macro. The approach is somewhat different, and you are limited to having a fixed set of known values:

```
#define OPS X_OP("abc", 3) X_OP("cdef", 2) X_OP("xx, 4)
```

When you use it, you temporarily define X_OP, selecting whatever you want. For example, the following will expand to `"abc", "cdef", "xx",` (note the trailing comma).

```
#define X_OP(name, value) name,
... OPS ...
#undef X_OP
```

The following will expand to `3, 4, 5,`:

```
#define X_OP(name, value) value,
... OPS ...
#undef X_OP
```

You can also do more advanced thing like:

```
#define X_OP(name, value) case value: return name;
char const * value_to_name(v)
{
  switch(v)
  {
    OPS
    default: return NULL;
  }
}
#undef X_OP
```